# Laravel, $.ajax POST does a GET request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I have a problem. My jquery submit function, tries to do a GET request, while I set it up as a POST request.

my submit function

```
function authenticate() {
var form = $('#form-login');
form.submit(function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    console.log('submitting!');
    console.log(form.serialize());
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://website.dev/loginz',
        data: form.serialize(),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) { log_error(data.error); }
    });
});
}
```

routes.php

```
Route::post('loginz', 'User\LoginController@authenticate');
```

What my chrome browser says

```
GET http://website.dev/loginz/ 405 (Method Not Allowed)
```

/Loginz

```
/* POST */
function authenticate(Request $request) {
    $username = $request->input('username');
    $password = $request->input('password');
    if(Auth::attempt(['username' => $username, 'password' => $password])) {
        redirect()->route('home'); /* should redirect to player */
    }
    return response()->json(['error' => trans('errors.user_password_combination').' => '.$username.' & '.$password]);
}
```

Maybe I am just stupid and hit a wall, I have stared myself to death and I just can't see the error :P

Comment: Check for the error in network tab...

Comment: Thanks, it did a 301 :S .. fixed it with url: http://website.dev/loginz/  .. added a slash, so it doesnt 301 to /

Comment: Please do not edit a solution into your question. Instead, post it as a separate answer below.

Answer (score 0):

What version of laravel are you using?

Remind csrf token must be given for post requests.

you can disable the csrf verification also in  `\App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,`

But would be better if you set in on the client side.
Meaning from laravel you should in the blade template add something like:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $.ajaxSetup({ headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': '{{ csrf_token() }}' } });
});
```

But first, in Chrome (example) inspector -> network -> header: what is the request method?

Answer (score 0):

The fault was an 301 redirect. The problem was created by myself. I added a redirect from non slash to slash (ex. /page to /page/) so the POST was redirected to a GET request.